# How can I import dart:html in a simple .dart script?

Tags: dart, dart-html

I want to execute a .dart file with dart:html core library, but I get this error(s). [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQ3PL.png)

Important: I'm not using Flutter.

Any ideas?

I've been looking for solutions to the following problem, but haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
Activate webdev:

dart pub global activate webdev

Create pubspec.yaml and add those dev_dependency:

lints: ^2.0.0
build_runner: ^2.1.4
build_web_compilers: ^3.2.1